# Laravel: How to flatten a multi-dimensional eager loaded Collection

Tags: php, laravel

I have got a collection with eager loaded nested descendants (Region models):

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1649 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Region {#1650 ▼
      ...
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "descendants" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1646 ▼
          #items: array:2 [▼
            0 => App\Models\Region {#1660 ▶}
              …
              #relations: array:1 [▼
                "descendants" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1657 ▼
                  #items: array:2 [▼
                    0 => App\Models\Region {#1672 ▶}
                    1 => App\Models\Region {#1671 ▶}
                  ]
            1 => App\Models\Region {#1659 ▶}
etc …
```

I want to flatten this whole collection into one single collection of the same class, in such way that the order in the new collection will be like this:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1676 ▼
  #items: array:10 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Region {#1650 ▶}    (parent)
    1 => App\Models\Region {#1660 ▶}    (child 1)
    2 => App\Models\Region {#1672 ▶}    (grandchild 1)
    3 => App\Models\Region {#1671 ▶}    (grandchild 2)
    4 => App\Models\Region {#1659 ▶}    (child 2)
etc …
```

I need it to be an eloquent collection of models, not a collection of arrays.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a recursive function that will flatten the collection.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

class RegionController
{
    public function flattenCollection(Collection $collection)
    {
        $flattenedCollection = new Collection();

        foreach ($collection as $region) {
            $flattenedCollection->push($region);

            if ($region->relationLoaded('descendants')) {
                $descendants = $this->flattenCollection($region->descendants);
                $flattenedCollection = $flattenedCollection->merge($descendants);
            }
        }

        return $flattenedCollection;
    }
}
```

Then, use the function to flatten.

```
$originalCollection = // your original collection with eager-loaded relationships;

$regionController = new RegionController();
$flattenedCollection = $regionController->flattenCollection($originalCollection);
```

Comment: YES it works ... Thanks Thanks Thanks !!!! One extra question: does a (build-in) laravel way of doing this exist?

Comment: I dont think Laravel provides a built-in method specifically designed to flatten a multi-dimensional eager-loaded collection in the way you described.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-flatten